# Is there anyway to load a local file into Ti.WKWebView?

Tags: appcelerator

Using https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/Ti.WKWebView I create my 'html content' on the fly using data from a JSON feed, and then pipe that into the WKWebView which works beautifully `WKWebView.setHtml(myContent);`

Now with a standard ti web view I have a line in the myContent variable (basically a giant string of HTML) that says `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myfiles/style.css" />` which would style things wonderfully.

This however doesn't work on WKWebview.  Upon further trial and error I see that I can't include any local files into WKWebView this way.  If I set it to a remote file on a web server, then it works just fine.

But for some reason it doesn't want to pull up local files.  Is this something with the design of Ti.WKWebView or am I doing something wrong?

Praying hansemannnn reads these pages as I can see no other way of creating an issue on Github

Comment: Did you try to use `html` as the documentation shows: https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/Ti.WKWebView#properties ? It is not a method but just a property

Comment: @miga yes so for example my html property = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myfiles/style.css" /><div class="awesome class">Hello!</div>'   and the words "awesome class" are shown, but not styled properly according to style.css, because style.css is not actually loaded

Comment: I'm not sure how picky Ti.WKWebView is, but did you try to inject a proper HTML structure, so put the `link` in the `head`? Do you need to use html? Can't you just save the page locally, load it and change the dynamic parts via javascript?

Comment: @miga yes it has full proper html structure with <html>, <head>, etc..

Comment: join us on http://tislack.org/ I think its quicker to find a solution there :) The author of the plugin is very active there, too

Comment: and you can use https://jira.appcelerator.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa to report bugs!